# Is there any way to restore commit history after you got deleted from the team?

Tags: bitbucket

I wonder ff there's any way to get history of my commits pushed to bitbucket, even if I'm not in team anymore.

Has any of you tried it? Or should I contact Atlassian directly?

Thanks!

Comment: Did the team ask you for some stuff that was not pushed to the repo yet? You can "git bundle" your local copy, send the file to them and have them import it.

Comment: Or do you want to download code from a private repository you longer have access to? That cannot work ...

Comment: @Thilo This is rather different story. I'd like to have an evidence that someone has pushed to that repo during the time I was in.

Comment: I don't want to download code, I just want to retrieve the history of activity in that repo

Comment: "the history of activity" is part of the repo (or at least the Bitbucket team account). That won't be accessible to non-team members. Atlassian won't give that out either, unless you have some court order or something like that.

Comment: The team owner *might* get a report somewhere of who pushed what when to the repo, but I haven't seen that feature.

Comment: The thing is I cannot ask team owner, because this is the case. They want not to pay for my job because it's "useless" and they won't use it (which is a silly argument itself), but I remember other devs from other company pushing to this repo, working on my code. And I would like to prove it